# Make Asp.net mvc application access remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

1- I have a deployed asp.net mvc5 application on iis 7.5 at Server1.
2- I have a scheduled task in server2.
When i log into Server1 with admin account i'm able to edit scheduled task on server2, but when i use normal account i'm not.
I need to know is their a way to make my asp application use admin account to make it able to edit scheduled task in Server2 

Here is the script i need to run in my web application

```
schtasks.exe /change /s Server2 /ru system /tn Test /sd 10/05/2015
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for a web application on server1 to start a process on another server (server2).

Comment: Even if the script is working well in command line of the same server as the web app ?

Comment: Yes, Imagine a web app can execute a process on client machines.

Comment: I see..., what about writing a script as .ps1  and make the app execute it ?